# How to tell autoconf about broken cross HOST functions?

Tags: android, autoconf

I am trying to cross-build an autotools enabled package for an unusual embedded system with a very incomplete libc.  (If it is relevant: The package is CPython 3.4.2 and the "embedded system" is the command line shell on Android 4.4.)

AFAIK there's no way that `configure` running on my build machine can determine which functions on the host are broken.  (`configure` can, and does, compile and link test programs on the build machine, but it has no access to running the program on the host.)  So, for example, the [`wcsftime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/wcsftime.html) function is declared in the host's `<wchar.h>` header and defined in the host's libc, but the implementation is incorrect.

For this package `configure` builds a `config.h` file with a C macro `HAS_WCSFTIME`, which is defined if `configure` believes the host has a working `wcsftime()` and is undef'd otherwise.  And the package's source code is correctly ifdefed so that if `wcsftime()` is missing, `strftime()` is used instead, with proper conversions back and forth between 7-bit ascii and UCS-4.

I can't just run `configure` with:

```
CPPFLAGS=-UHAS_WCSFTIME configure --build=... --host=... ...
```

because the config.h file just redefines it anyway.

The options I've come up with so far are:

1. add a `ac_cv_broken_host_wcsftime` variable to the configure.ac file
2. add `ifdef`s for a `HAS_BROKEN_WCSFTIME` macro to the sources
3. fix the host's libc
4. create a patch for config.h that flips HAS_WCSFTIME from defined to undefined, and remember to run `patch` every time after I run `configure`

I've already implemented option (4) and it is ... unsatisfying.  I can do (1) or (2) and contribute it back to the package developers, but then it will be months before the changes get incorporated.  I'm working on option (3), but that will take years to get deployed to the majority of my user's phones and tablets.

What's the right way to deal with this problem?  (I expect it to come up a lot since I've got a lot of different packages that I want to get working, and there are dozens of broken functions in libc.)

Is there some command line option to `configure` that will let me control which CPP macros do and do not get defined?

Comment: Hello! A) Were you using the Google NDK, or were you using the CrystaX NDK? B) Why would you like to run CPython on Android? Cheers!

Comment: @unforgettableid (a) Google NDK.  I'd not heard of CrystaX before.  (b) I'm trying to get iPython and the numpy/scipy stack working so I can have an interactive math environment on my tablet.  Inspired by the (now defunct) http://computableapp.com/ for iPad.  For many simple Python apps on Android, Jython would make more sense than CPython, but Jython doesn't support CPython's C API sufficiently, and large hunks of numpy/scipy are written to the CPython C API.

Comment: There's no cost to use the CrystaX NDK other than your time. (Though I do admit that time is the most precious commodity in the world.)  Does CPython compile fine using that NDK?

Comment: @unforgettableid, I started downloading it as soon as I saw your first message.  I won't be able to try it until later in the week.  I'll tell you how it goes.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Please keep us updated :)

Comment: 1. Is your tablet connected to the Internet? Could you connect to iPython on another machine, using either a) SSH or b) HTML and JavaScript? 2. Or could you install a traditional Linux userland on the tablet, perhaps using "GNURoot Debian" or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some command line option to configure that will let me control which CPP macros do and do not get defined?

No.

Your best bet is to talk with the package maintainers.  They can help you put an acceptable patch together for their package.  You can then apply this patch until it gets pushed with the following method.

As an alternative to 4), you could also patch `configure` itself, especially if there's a bootstrap script that is invoked to create `configure`.  Doing actions in the bootstrap script to fix up `configure` or `libtool`, etc. is one of the ways I've solved this problem in the past.

If in 3) you mean Bionic as libc, I'd think that "never" is probably a more accurate timetable than "takes years" to get wide character functions into it.

> AFAIK there's no way that configure running on my build machine can determine which functions on the host are broken. (configure can, and does, compile and link test programs on the build machine, but it has no access to running the program on the host.)

Mostly true.  [Scratchbox2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratchbox2) will allow you to do runtime `configure` tests on the host, but it doesn't support Android, unfortunately.